# How to display maximum hidden value line in top of maximum x axis mpandroidchart?

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

when I add label in top and bottom, there is a horizontal line in top and bottom which works perfectly.

But when I display label only in bottom, the horizontal line at top is not displaying and it's displaying only in bottom. How to display horizontal line at top of the graph?

Here is Screenshot..

Sceanrio 1: When I show both label in top and bottom works good by showing line.

[image]

Scenario 2:

You can see where line is missing in top of the x axis label ie above 11. 12 is not displaying.

[image]

```
    barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_back_button);
    textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_names);
    barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    barChart.setDescription("");
    barChart.getViewPortHandler().setMaximumScaleX(1f);
    barChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below methods,

> setDrawAxisLine(boolean enabled): Set this to true if the line
>   alongside the axis (axis-line) should be drawn or not.
>
> setDrawGridLines(boolean enabled): Set this to true to enable drawing
>   the grid lines for the axis.

check [The Axis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis) and [Documentation of the MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki)

Comment: you can try implmenting above two methods and check result.

Comment: hi this reduce number at bottom to 1.

Comment: xAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true); try this